# How to get max value from JSON?

Tags: json, max, jq

There is a json file like this:

```
[
{
    "createdAt": 1548729542000,
    "platform": "foo"
},
{
    "createdAt": 1548759398000,
    "platform": "foo"
},
{
    "createdAt": 1548912360000,
    "platform": "foo"
},
{
    "createdAt": 1548904550000,
    "platform": "bar"
}
]
```

Now I want to get the max createdAt of foo platform? how to implement it by using jq?

```
jq '.[] | select(.platform=="foo") | .createdAt | max' foo.json
jq: error (at <stdin>:17): number (1548729542000) and number (1548729542000) cannot be iterated over

jq '.[] | select(.platform=="foo") | max_by(.createdAt)' foo.json
jq: error (at <stdin>:17): Cannot index number with string "createdAt"
exit status 5
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`max` expects an array as input.

```
$ jq 'map(select(.platform == "foo") .createdAt) | max' file
1548912360000
```

Comment: Answer would be better if it explained more. If I take the example json and `jq '.[] | select(.platform=="foo") | .createdAt'` then it apparently outputs rows. `map` takes an array and outputs a new array. So it's not clear to me why `map` works here... well, the fact it works indicates that original query didn't produce an array, but I don't understand the difference.

Comment: @Anentropic the difference is that `.[] | select(.platform=="foo") | .createdAt` yields numbers and `map(select(.platform=="foo") | .createdAt)` yields an array. When you do `1, 2, 3 | max`, `max` is applied to each number (and fail because they aren't arrays); when you do `[1, 2, 3] | max` it is applied to the whole array (and return the element with maximum value).

Comment: Thanks, I have been working it out by trial and error... I was finding confusing the distinction between returned rows (not an array itself, but each row might be an array) and collecting rows into an array and returning that. Your answer has helped me though.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to make the selection and then use one of the array-oriented builtins `max` or `max_by` to find the maximum, e.g.

```
map(select(.platform=="foo"))
| max_by(.createdAt)
| .createdAt
```

However, this approach is not very satisfactory as it requires more space than is strictly necessary.  For large arrays, a stream-oriented version of `max_by` would be better.

### max_by

```
def max_by(s; f):
  reduce s as $s (null;
    if . == null then {s: $s, m: ($s|f)}
    else  ($s|f) as $m
    | if $m > .m then {s: $s, m: $m} else . end
    end)
  | .s ;

max_by(.[] | select(.platform=="foo"); .createdAt)
| .createdAt
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
cat foo.json | jq -c '.[] | select(.platform=="foo") | .createdAt' | sort -un | tail -1
```

JSON -> list of numbers -> sort (unique) all by number, asc -> get last (max)